# Solspace freeform pro and relationships

Tags: solspace-freeform, relationships, related-entries

Is it possible to create relationships in freeform pro similar to how you can create relationships between channels?

I have two channels, a freeform for each, and a need to relate the information from each using a third form. I know I can do a lot of this using channel forms but I really like some of the functionality that freeform gives me.

I guess a third option is to tie in the freeform into the channel as written in the freeform docs.

If anyone has any suggestions I would certainly welcome your input. Thank you.

Comment: "_I have two channels, a freeform for each_" => Can you elaborate? Do you mean you store channel data in a Freeform form? "_and a need to relate the information from each using a third form_" => Do you mean store data from the previous 2 Freeform forms into yet another (3rd) Freeform form?

Comment: Sure thing. I am storing the data for each channel in a Freeform form, so there are currently no channel entries for either channel,only Freeform entries. The first channel is called Theatres, and I'm using a Freeform form to allow theatre owners to add and edit theatres. I'm then displaying the freeform entries in a table so the owners can view/edit their theatres. The second channel is called Admin, and I'm using a Freeform form to allow Super Admins to add new movies/features. I'm displaying all features in a table for this channel as well.

Comment: If there are no _Channel Entries_, why are you calling these _Freeform forms_ "Channels"? Sorry, but I'm confused.

Comment: The final piece I need to add is a Booking form (the 3rd form) that lists a single feature and the theatres of the logged in theatre owner. I need to place a field out next to each theatre that allows the owners to input the number of prints/screens they will have available for that particular feature. Then I'll send notifications upon submit. I'm just not sure if I can do what I need to with Freeform in this scenario. I hope the extra info helps and makes sense. I appreciate your time and feedback. Let me know if you need additional info. Thx

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. You are correct. Technically they're not channels and are really Freeform entries. I have channels set up if necessary. So I do apologize for the confusion.

Comment: Thanks, I think there is enough to give a suggested solution. You will need to further tweak to your own specific needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend reading the comments to the opening post for more details about the question. There are no "*Channels*" in this setup, only Freeform forms (forms were simply described as similar to "channels" in the opening post).

### Summary

There are currently 2 Freeform forms:

- **Theatres**: Contains *theatre* information
- **Admin**: Contains other *theatre* and *movie* information

### The Goal

A 3rd form is needed, called **Booking**, which contains data from the first 2 forms.

### A Suggested Solution<sup>*</sup>

> <sup>*</sup> As with most things EE, more than one solution is possible. This is only one possible strategy.

You can build this using `{exp:freeform:form}` and `{exp:freeform:entries}`. Let's say you have 3 fields in the **Booking** form set up to store data:

- `movie`
- `theatre`: the field will be populated with entries from the **Theatres** form for the currently logged in user
- `no_of_prints`

You could build the form this way (**this is just an example**):

```
{exp:freeform:form form_name="booking" /* your other parameters here */}

    {!-- The movie --}
    {exp:freeform:entries form_name="admin" search:movie_name="Snowpiercer"}
        <input type="text" name="movie" value="{freeform:field:movie}" />
    {/exp:freeform:entries}

    {!-- The theatre --}
    <select name="theatre">
        <option>-- Select a theatre --</option>
        {exp:freeform:entries form_name="theatres" author_id="CURRENT_USER"}
        <option value="{freeform:field:theatre_name}">{freeform:field:theatre_name}</option>
        {/exp:freeform:entries}
    </select>

    {!-- The Number of Prints/Screens --}
    <input type="text" name="no_of_prints" placeholder="Eg. 50" />

    <input type="submit" />
{/exp:freeform:form}
```

If you have custom fields with the same name across Freeform forms, you might run into issues where tags such as `{freeform:field:movie}` get parsed as a *field*, since it's within `{exp:freeform:form}`, when you really wanted a *value*, since it's also within `{exp:freeform:entries}`. In that case, use embed templates to isolate the `{exp:freeform:entries}` tag code.

Comment: Great. I see what I was doing wrong now and this gives me a really good idea for next steps. Thank you for the additional info too. I will let you know how it goes. I really appreciate your time and assistance!